# How to insert into database from List<Object> (nested) using JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have 3 different tables in which I want to insert my data which comes in the form of JSON. Following is how my data is structured.

Stream Class:

```
public class StreamsID {
    private Long id;
    private Long campaign_id;
    private Long credential_id;
    private String user_id;
    private String custom_name;
    private List<Item> items;
}
```

Item class:

```
public class Item {
    private Long stream_id;
    private String stream_item_date;
    private String channel;
    private List<Workflow> workflow;
    private List<Responses> responses;
```

Workflow Class:

```
public class Workflow {
    public static final String FIND_ALL = "findAll";
    private Long id;
    private User actor;
    private User assignee;
    private String date;
    private String team;
    private String action;
```

I am using PreparedStatement to insert the data:

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO public.streams(" +
                        "stream_id, stream_campaign_id," +
                        "stream_user_id, stream_custom_name) " +
                        "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);");
        statement.setLong(1,stream.getId());
        statement.setLong(2,stream.getCampaign_id());
        statement.setLong(3,stream.getCredential_id());
        statement.setString(4,stream.getUser_id());
        statement.setString(5,stream.getCustom_name());
```

The problem with this approach is that i am unable to save the Item and workflow tables. I am not sure how to implement this in JDBC. The database we are using is Postgresql.

This was far easier when i used JPA but we had to switch to JDBC for some constraints. Any help with this is highly appreciated.

Comment: why are you unable to save the `item` & `workflow` tables? What error do you get?

Comment: I dont get any error! just that the data is not being saved in the table.

Comment: _For each_  `Item`s in the `List<Item> items`, INSERT the `Item` with the current `Stream` id. This is that easy. I suggest you take a good look at transaction to be able to rollback everything in case of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To insert `List` on JDBC you need to use loop, and call [addBatch()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch()).
To `Item`(assuming there's a `StreamsID` called `stream`), it should be something like this:

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO item(stream_id,"+
                                          "stream_item_date, channel) "+
                                          "VALUES (?, ?, ?);");
for(Item item : stream.getItems()){
    statement.setLong(1, item.getStream_id());
    statement.setString(2, item.getStream_item_date());
    statement.setString(3, item.getChannel());
    statement.addBatch();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Let me try this.

Comment: At one point, you should execute the batch or this will not work. But batch is not mandatory, you can simply execute the statement, a batch is just a must for big data load.

Comment: I would suggest adding `connection.setAutoCommit(false);` before preparing the statement and then executing the batch with `statement.executeBatch();` followed by, finally, `connection.commit();`

Comment: Thanks a lot @M Jr.